# How to change tabs according to the day?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-timepicker

What changes should i make in the code so that Tabs are opened according to the system Day (ie Monday, Tuesday...)? In the last code i have used calander class to get the Day from the system but how can i implement it in the 1st and 2nd code so that on opening the app the corresponding tab(is the current day-like today is 2 aug Sunday so sunday should open) is opened?

```
package com.example.timetabletest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

ActionBar actionbar;
ViewPager viewpager;
FragmentPageAdapter ft;

private String[] tabs = { "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY",
        "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
    actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    viewpager.setAdapter(ft);
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
    blowUp.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;

}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
        Intent abt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUs.class);
        startActivity(abt);
        break;
    }
    return false;
}

public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

---

```
package com.example.timetabletest;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

 public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0) {
    case 0:
        return new MondayFragment();
    case 1:
        return new TuesdayFragment();
    case 2:
        return new WedFragment();
    case 3:
        return new ThursdayFragment();
    case 4:
        return new FridayFragment();
    case 5:
        return new SatFragment();

    default:
        break;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 6;
}

 }
```

---

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    String weekDay = null;

    if (Calendar.MONDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "monday";
    } else if (Calendar.TUESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "tuesday";
    } else if (Calendar.WEDNESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "wednesday";
    } else if (Calendar.THURSDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "thursday";
    } else if (Calendar.FRIDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "friday";
    } else if (Calendar.SATURDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "saturday";
    } else if (Calendar.SUNDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "sunday";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the line below to set your current tab.

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
//The true is if you want to do a smooth scroll to your page.
//If you don't want to scroll, you can put false.
```

Put this code right at the bottom of your onCreate method and it should work.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

if (Calendar.MONDAY == dayOfWeek) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
} else if (Calendar.TUESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
} else if (Calendar.WEDNESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
} else if (Calendar.THURSDAY == dayOfWeek) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3, true);
} else if (Calendar.FRIDAY == dayOfWeek) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(4, true);
} else if (Calendar.SATURDAY == dayOfWeek) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(5, true);
} else if (Calendar.SUNDAY == dayOfWeek) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(6, true);
}
```